# Unidentified color changing object in sky

Tags: astrophysics, identify-this-object

Yesterday, I was just star gazing and I noticed some star-like object moving with a high speed somewhere near the Orion's Belt and exhibiting all the seven colors i.e VIBGYOR and after a few moments, it disappeared. Any plausible explanations for this observation?

Comment: Can you give more specifics on where you were when you observed this?

Comment: I have never seen anyone put the rainbow in that order.

Comment: If it appeared to be moving fast, then it was probably nearby. Maybe someone goofing around with a quad-copter with multi-coloured LEDs. Forget it. In any case, how do you distinguish indigo from violet?

Comment: Well, I was trying to say that it exhibited random colors every second. This was observed three days ago in Chennai near the Orion's Belt.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because starlike objects that are changing colour rapidly cannot be astronomical. Please look at the other UFO reports here to see why we can't answer them.

Answer (score -1):

## Probably a satellite flare

It sounds like a [satellite flare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellite_flare).

Coming, showing up clearly for a few moments, moving, then going away, are characteristic of a satellite flare, like Iridium flashes.

Check [Heavens Above](http://www.heavens-above.com/) or [any other similar site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_satellite_pass_predictors) to see if any predicted flares match with your location and time.

The changing colours can be explained with "[Twinkling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twinkling)".